# Building an iterator recursively results in "recursive opaque type" error

Tags: rust

I have a struct which owns a `Vec` and has an optional reference to a parent struct of its own type. I want a iterator that iterates over the items and then if there is a parent recursively iterate.

I currently have the following, **but** it allocates on the heap and uses dynamic dispatch:

```rust
struct Struct1 {
    items: Vec<(String, i32)>, 
    parent: Option<Rc<Struct1>>
}

impl Struct1 {
    pub fn keys<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a str> + 'a> {
        let iter = self.items.iter().map(|(key, _)| key.as_str());
        if let Some(child) = &self.parent {
            Box::new(iter.chain(child.keys()))
        } else {
            Box::new(iter)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a alternative way to write the `keys()` implementation which doesn't allocate on the heap or use dynamic dispatch?

I am thinking of the following:

```rust
impl Struct1 {
    fn keys<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> {
        let iter = self.0.iter().map(|(key, _)| key.as_str());
        if let Some(child) = &self.1 {
            Either2::A(iter.chain(child.keys()))
        } else {
            Either2::B(iter)
        }
    }
}

pub enum Either2<A, B> {
    A(A),
    B(B),
}

impl<T, A: Iterator<Item = T>, B: Iterator<Item = T>> Iterator for Either2<A, B> {
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self {
            Self::A(a) => a.next(),
            Self::B(b) => b.next(),
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not compile due to there being a recursive opaque type here `impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>`. And I can see why as the `Either2::A` is needed for the opaque type but also uses the opaque type.

Is there a way I could restructure the `impl ...` type reference to be recursive aware (possibly by using a `type` statement)? Or is there another way to rewrite the whole function to get it to work that doesn't involve intermediately collecting (and allocating) into a `vec`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These recursive structures *also* have a small performance problem: they build the entire parent-iterator chain before the first item is examined, even if the iterator will never reach the parent items. Instead, we can follow the `parent` chain and, separately, map each `&Struct1` we iterate over to an iterator of its own keys. This way, the recursive iterator structure has been “flattened” into an “iterative” one that is efficient and accepted by the compiler:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Struct1 {
    items: Vec<(String, i32)>,
    parent: Option<Rc<Struct1>>,
}

impl Struct1 {
    pub fn keys(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &str> + '_ {
        // Construct an iterator that follows parent references.
        let mut current: Option<&Struct1> = Some(self);
        let parents_iter = std::iter::from_fn(move || {
            let result = current;
            if let Some(Struct1 { parent, .. }) = current {
                // .as_deref() turns &Option<Rc<Struct1>> into Option<&Struct1>
                current = parent.as_deref();
            }
            result
        });

        parents_iter.flat_map(|p| p.only_self_keys())
    }

    fn only_self_keys(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &str> {
        self.items.iter().map(|(key, _)| key.as_str())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = Struct1 {
        items: vec![(String::from("a"), 1)],
        parent: Some(Rc::new(Struct1 {
            items: vec![(String::from("b"), 2), (String::from("c"), 3)],
            parent: None,
        })),
    };

    dbg!(input.keys().collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

One could also write a separate parent iterator struct that implements `Iterator` explicitly rather than using `std::iter::from_fn`.